# Change Page Ordering

Tags: formatting

In one of my documents, the first few (lets say 2) pages include code output and settings and configurations, in terms of communicating with R for example (for plotting etc...), I would like these pages to appear at the rear of the document, or split off into a second document.

They need to be 'typeset' in the **original** order, since much of the appearance of the document thereafter, is dependent on what is defined in this pre-section. The actual contents of the output to the pre-section, however, is trivial to the reader of the actual document, however, of interest to me.

How can I re-arrange or split the document post typesetting, to either remove the first 2 pages into a new document, or, move them to the end of the current document.

Comment: have you looked at the `pdfpages` package?

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what in those "pre-sections" is relevant for the following material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the question...

```
\AtEndDocument{
   %Add Content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem but if the first couple pages are just settings, you could create an `.sty` file, say `mysettings.sty`, with all your customizations and in the original document replace the first couple pages with `\usepackage{mysettings}`.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work here. The settings are actually 'R' settings, not latex settings, they are defined at runtime from inside \begin{document} \end{document} to define the 'R' environment, certain output is returned, and that output is what is being inserted into the document. I want the output, so I can refer back to it later in version control. It needs to be done at the start, but I want the output to be put at the end (or in a separate file)

Comment: @ADP Have you thought about using the commands `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument`?

Comment: @Jay, that solved my problem. If you want to post as a complete answer, I'll mark it as a solution...